# QML item fixed positioning

Tags: qt, keyboard, position, qml

The mobile devices move the elements up the the keyboard is called, but there are elements that stay in the same position when the device's keyboard appears like the images below.

How can I keep a Qml item fixed in the same position when device's keyboard appears?

I need that the `Rectangle` with `id: principal` stays fixed in the same position.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

Window {
    visible: true

    property int larguraTela: 360
    property int alturaTela: 640

    width: larguraTela
    height: alturaTela

    maximumWidth: larguraTela
    maximumHeight: alturaTela

    minimumWidth: larguraTela
    minimumHeight: alturaTela

    title: "OverStatusBar"

    Rectangle {
        id: principal

        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height * 0.15

        anchors.top: parent.top

        color: "orange"
    }

    Rectangle {

        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height * 0.85

        anchors.top: principal.bottom

        clip: true

        Rectangle{
            id: retangulo1

            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height * 0.5

            anchors.top: parent.top

            color: "grey"
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: retangulo2

            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height * 0.5

            anchors.top: retangulo1.bottom

            color: "lightgrey"

            TextField {
                id: campoTexto

                width: parent.width * 0.7
                height: parent.height * 0.20

                anchors.centerIn: parent

                inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly

            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image] [image]

Comment: I was reading some stuff here, and I figured out that what I want is something that works as the iOS navigation bar. There is any Type in Qml that can do that? I tried StackView, but it also moves up when the keyboard appears.

Comment: I have same issue here, but I just need the header fixed on top when user is scrolling items. Is there any answer for this?

Comment: I could not find it Hobas. I have just started programming in Swift and Android. I know it is a lot of work once it is needed to write the code in two languages but I think it was my best decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a long research about this topic I have concluded that there is no possible solution, at least until now, that doesn't involve a lot of workaround programming to solve that using cross-platform programming. I have tried a bunch of cross-platform languages with no satisfactory solution that could be implemented. The languages I tried were:

- QML
- Appcelerator (Titanium)
- PhoneGap (Cordova)
- Native Script
- React Native

My conclusion is that if I want do develop native look and feel apps that work as expected and without bugs, I need to do it using the native programming languages, even if I need to develop it twice in different languages. And that is what I am doing from now: XCode and Android Studio.

If someone would like to take a look at a piece of code to start doing it in QML just access the link [clicking here](http://forum.qt.io/topic/62365/qml-item-fixed-positioning/14):

> I have something very hackish and begging for refinement but I think it is going into the right direction :
>
> ```
> import QtQuick 2.4
> import QtQuick.Window 2.2
> import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
> Window {
>     visible: true
>     property int larguraTela: 360
>     property int alturaTela: 640
>     width: larguraTela
>     height: alturaTela
>     maximumWidth: larguraTela
>     maximumHeight: alturaTela
>     minimumWidth: larguraTela
>     minimumHeight: alturaTela
>     title: "OverStatusBar"
>     Rectangle {
>         id: principal
>         width: parent.width
>         height: parent.height * 0.15
>         anchors.top: parent.top
>         color: "orange"
>     }
>     Timer{
>         id:resetKeyboard
>         interval: 500
>         onTriggered: {
>             Qt.inputMethod.hide();
>             Qt.inputMethod.show();
>             unlock.restart();
>         }
>     }
>     Timer{
>         id:unlock
>         interval: 500
>
>         onTriggered: {
>             flickable.updateSlideContent = true;
>         }
>     }
>
>     Flickable{
>         id:flickable
>         width: parent.width
>         height : slideContent ? parent.height * 0.5 : parent.height * 0.85
>         anchors.top: principal.bottom
>         clip: true
>         contentHeight: parent.height * 0.85
>         contentY : slideContent ? parent.height*0.35 : 0
>
>         property bool updateSlideContent : true
>         property bool slideContent : false
>         property bool keyboardVisible : Qt.inputMethod.visible
>         onKeyboardVisibleChanged: {
>             if (updateSlideContent) {
>                 slideContent = keyboardVisible;
>                 if (keyboardVisible)
>                 {
>                     updateSlideContent = false;
>                     resetKeyboard.restart();
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>
>         Rectangle {
>
>             anchors.fill: parent
>
>
>
>
>             Rectangle{
>                 id: retangulo1
>
>                 width: parent.width
>                 height: parent.height * 0.5
>
>                 anchors.top: parent.top
>
>                 color: "grey"
>             }
>
>             Rectangle {
>                 id: retangulo2
>
>                 width: parent.width
>                 height: parent.height * 0.5
>
>                 anchors.top: retangulo1.bottom
>
>                 color: "lightgrey"
>
>                 TextField {
>                     id: campoTexto
>
>                     width: parent.width * 0.7
>                     height: parent.height * 0.20
>
>                     anchors.centerIn: parent
>
>                     inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly
>
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>
>     }
> }
> ```